# Upload file using IdHTTP to specified host based on curl call

Tags: delphi, curl, firemonkey, indy

I am trying to create an FMX Android application that needs to upload a file to given host.

The host owner provided me with a following `curl` statement to upload a file:

```
curl -T http://<ip-address>:<port> file.txt
```

And when called from Windows Command Prompt it produces the following output (IP and port redacted):

```
*   Trying <ip-address>...
* TCP_NODELAY set
* Connected to <ip-address> (<ip-address>) port <port> (#0)
> PUT /file.txt HTTP/1.1
> Host: <ip-address>:<port>
> User-Agent: curl/7.55.1
> Accept: */*
> Content-Length: 682
> Expect: 100-continue
>
* Done waiting for 100-continue
* We are completely uploaded and fine
< HTTP/1.1 200 OK
< content-length: 0
< date: Tue, 16 Jun 2020 19:24:18 GMT
< connection: close
<
* Closing connection 0
```

and file is visible in the expected directory on the host machine.

Now I'm trying to have the same behavior using Indy, but either there is some black-box magic occurring on the server-side, or there is an issue with my code - with some solutions the request seems to finalize, but there is no file in the specified directory (and status code 200 is returned).

I have also tried using Fiddler to reproduce the `curl` call, and in the response of a composed query also received 200 status code, but still - no file was properly uploaded.

When inspecting Wireshark packets for these solutions they all seemed similar to the curl call - however, I am not an expert in using this tool, so maybe there are issues not visible to my newbie eye.

I tried using following solutions:
- [How do I upload a file using http post? Delphi 2009](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10889511/how-do-i-upload-a-file-using-http-post-delphi-2009) - but using PUT instead of POST
- [Single file upload example](https://mikejustin.wordpress.com/2019/02/18/single-file-upload-example-using-indy-tidhttp-and-multipart-form-data/)
- [Post a file through https using indy / delphi components](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18522286/post-a-file-through-https-using-indy-delphi-components)

And in my case they do not work - so my guess is that the server is somehow not accepting these.

I know it's very hard to say what I'm doing wrong without me actually putting some code, but right now it's a total mess - but maybe it's not hard to somehow show me how to convert this curl call to work with `TIdHttp`?

If not, I will try to modify my question soon with more information.

**EDIT:** As requested, I'm adding some sample code:

```
var
  FHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  file2send: string;
  sr: TStringStream;
  FPutData : TFileStream;
begin
  sr := TStringStream.Create;
  if OpenDialog1.Execute then
    file2send := OpenDialog1.FileName;

  FHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(self);
  FPutData := TFileStream.Create(file2send, fmOpenRead or
    fmShareDenyWrite);
  FHTTP.Put(PutURL.text, FPutData, sr);

end;
```

Comment: Please show the actual code you are having trouble with. The curl command you have shown is very easy to replicate using `TIdHTTP.Put()` and a `TFileStream`.  But, if you can't even produce a valid result using Fiddler instead of Indy, then chances are there is a problem on the server side.

Comment: Hi @RemyLebeau, thanks for your response. As per request, I added some sample code. Could you verify if I'm using Indy and FileStream properly?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You don't need the `TStringStream` since you don't use it. You can pass `TStream(nil)` in that parameter.

Also, you are calling `FHTTP.Put()` unconditionally, even if `OpenDialog.Execute()` returns false.

Also, make sure the URL you pass to `FHTTP.Put()` is `'http://<ip-address>:<port>/file.txt'` not `'http://<ip-address>:<port>'`.

Also, consider setting `FHTTP.Request.UserAgent`, as some web servers reject Indy's default `UserAgent`.

Also, consider `Free`'ing your objects, especially if you ever plan to upgrade to 10.4 Sydney or later, since ARC for object lifetime management was removed in 10.4.

Try something more like this:

```pascal
var
  FHTTP: TIdHTTP;
  file2send: string;
  FPutData : TFileStream;
begin
  if not OpenDialog1.Execute then Exit;

  file2send := OpenDialog1.FileName;

  FHTTP := TIdHTTP.Create(nil);
  try
    FHTTP.Request.UserAgent := 'curl/7.55.1';
    FPutData := TFileStream.Create(file2send, fmOpenRead or fmShareDenyWrite);
    try
      FHTTP.Put(PutURL.Text, FPutData, TStream(nil));
      { or, maybe something like:
      URL := PutURL.Text + '/' + ExtractFileName(file2send);
      FHTTP.Put(URL, FPutData, TStream(nil));
      }
    finally
      FPutData.Free;
    end;
  finally
    FHTTP.Free;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: "Also, make sure the URL you pass to FHTTP.Put() is 'http://<ip-address>:<port>/file.txt' not 'http://<ip-address>:<port>'." <- this! I'm not sure how I missed this. Works for Windows application, so now I only need to check if Android works properly, but I think the answer to the question is this. For your other remarks (conditional running of Put(), setting user agent and freeing my objects - this was minimal example, but none the less, they are very helpful. Thank you for your time and support :)